# Exception error in Java while attempting sorting

Tags: java, exception

i am doing sorts in java and i have ran into an error. The error is stemming from my class file and then the tester i have in turn, wont work. Here is the class

```
import java.util.*;

public class CompanyDataBase
{
    ArrayList<Employee> employee = new ArrayList<Employee>();
}

//Default Constructor
public CompanyDataBase()
{

}

//Methods
//Add Employee
public void addEmployee(Employee newGuy)
{
   employee.add(newGuy);
}

//Get the employees
public ArrayList<Employee> getEmployees()
{
   return employee;
}

//Sort by name
public ArrayList<Employee> sortByName()
{
   Collections.sort(employee, new EmployeeNameComparator());
   return employee;
}

//Sort by salary
public ArrayList<Employee> sortBySalary()
{
   Collections.sort(employee, new EmployeeSalaryComparator());
   return employee;
}

//Bubble Sort
public void bubblesortBySalary(int [] employee)
{
    int temp = 0;
    boolean arraySorted = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < employee.length - 1 && !arraySorted;
                            i++ )
    {
    arraySorted = true;   // start a new iteration;
                          //  maybe the array is sorted

    for ( int j = 0; j < employee.length - i - 1; j++ )
    {
       if ( employee[j] > employee[j + 1] )
       {
          // swap the adjacent elements
          //   and set arraySorted to false
          temp = employee[j + 1];
          employee[j + 1] = employee[j];
          employee[j] = temp;
          arraySorted = false;
       }
    }
 }
```

}

}

Also here is the tester that i am using

```
public class BubbleSortTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        CompanyDataBase myDb = new CompanyDataBase();

        myDb.addEmployee(new Employee("James, John", 34, 45234));
        myDb.addEmployee(new Employee("Conroy, Mike", 19, 19234));
        myDb.addEmployee(new Employee("Gavigan, Luke", 28, 30234));
        myDb.addEmployee(new Manager("Gates, Bill", 28, 44000, 2000));

        myDb.bubblesortBySalary();


        for(Employee currEmployee: myDb.getEmployees())
        {
            System.out.println(currEmployee.getDescription());
        }

    }
}
```

The problem i am having is that when i attempt to compile my tester it gives me the following error >>>>
 BubbleSortTester.java:16: error: method bubblesortBySalary in class CompanyDataBase cannot be applied to given types;
      myDb.bubblesortBySalary();
          ^
  required: int[]
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

I then tried it in Eclipse instead of jGrasp and that advised me to enter null but when i enter null it returns this error >>>
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at CompanyDataBase.bubblesortBySalary(CompanyDataBase.java:46)
    at BubbleSortTester.main(BubbleSortTester.java:16)

Sorry for the amount of code but any help would be appreciated, 
Thanks in advance,
Jason

Answer (score 2):

You have called `bubblesortBySalary` as:

```
myDb.bubblesortBySalary();
```

but your definition of the method is

```
public void bubblesortBySalary(int[] employee){
   ....
}
```

So the method was expecting an `int[]` but didn't recieve one

#### Possible solution

You method appears to expect an array of integers to sort which it calls employees, you **also** have an instance field called employees which I believe you may be intending to sort. If so you will need to provide some method to compare Employees and remove the passed `int[]`. If you just want to sort integers you need to provide those integers to the method

Answer (score 2):

The function `bubblesortBySalary();` requires an argument of type `int[]`. You need to supply that for this to compile.

Passing `null` makes the compiler happy, but doesn't solve the fundamental problem that you haven't supplied an array to be sorted. Once you define the array, such as `int[] employee = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4}`, pass it to the function as `myDb.bubblesortBySalary(employee);`.